# excel. looking to add an additional month once todays date hits the 16th of the month. I need to push docs to the following month

Tags: excel, formula

I am allowed to offer a forbearance plan for 12 months.  Max 3 month forbearance.  when the 15th of the month hits...I need to provide additional time for the borrower to receive docs.   I just need excel to add an additional month to my calc once the date hits the 16th.

I have excel set up stating how delinquent the loan is.  excel shows the # of months delinquent.  I am looking to add an additional month to my calc once the 16th of the month hits.    My fixed inputs are a due date.
The current tool inputs are.., Todays date.   The tool tells me how many months the loan is delinquent...Looking to add an additional month once the Todays date hits the 16th-31st

Answer (score 1):

Working with dates is rather easy to work with when you know it's technically a number that's going up by 1 per day. You can also create a date while being able to do calculations for what month for example.

Here's a an easy way:

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY())<16, TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,DAY(TODAY())))
```

I believe I've seen an easier version bouncing around but this formula speaks for itself ^^